# $('#element').css("CssProperty") is not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am using jquery .css() function to get 'margin-left' property using `var divMargin= $('#DivId').css('margin-left')` but i am getting `undefined` in `divMargin` some times this works perfectly and some times causes problem

```
var divMargin= $('#DivId').css('margin-left');
```

what is cause of such unexpected behavior?

Comment: What's the result of $('#DivId') ?

Comment: Does using marginLeft (name of JS property) instead of margin-left help? It might have more consistent behaviour.

Comment: i think he should give some value

Comment: Have you: `#DivId { margin-left: 40px; }` in css?

Comment: Without more information, the question cannot be answered properly. As you can see, you already have three different answers. Make sure the element exists before you call that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your script inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var divMargin= $('#DivId').css('margin-left'); 
})
```

So it run after DOM is loaded

Comment: yes i was accessing $('#DivId') before it is completely loaded so now it works fine for me. thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.css()` does not return the computed style. It'll get you only those CSS properties that you set via `.css(..)` calls if I remember correctly. For getting a currently set CSS property no matter where it is set from, you can use `window.getComputedStyle`

Use this for getting the computed style for an element:

```
window.getComputedStyle(element);
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

For margin-left, you can do:

```
var marginLeft = window.getComputedStyle($('#DivId')[0]).marginLeft;
```

Comment: Would this also work if margin left is part of a shorthand margin property? Like this -> "margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px"

Comment: According to the `.css()` documentation, it should return the computed values as well.

Comment: @Sam - Yes, it will. It will return the final computed CSS property value. i.e. the one the value used by the browser to do the rendering.

Comment: @FelixKling - Yes, but I've experienced it not working well when the styles do not come from one of my own .css() calls (that was long ago) - Now a days, i stick to `getComputedStyle` for such requirements.

Comment: Ok, but it does work, see http://jsfiddle.net/wR7XZ/, so the problem is likely to be something else...

Comment: @FelixKling - Hmm.. Looks like that. This happened a few years ago when jQuery was at i don't know 1.2 or something - maybe its patched up in recent versions.

Comment: @BrainCoder - what version of jQuery are you using?